# How to add sources from qml modules to qt_add_translations in Qt6 CMake?

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, qt6

I am having trouble with setting up translation files in my Qt6 application using CMake.

I think my issue is not restricted to qml files, but I will use here only qml files to keep my case simple.

I'm working on a project with submodules to organize my cpp and qml files.
As an example, lets say I have a root project called `appTestLocalization` containing a `Main.qml` and a module `MyModule` in a directory `MyModule` containing a `MyText.qml`.
Each of the qml files contains one `qsTr()` in them.

I want to add localizations to my app, and following the [qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/localization.html#specify-translation-sources-in-qt-project-files) I add a [qt_add_translations()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlinguist-cmake-qt-add-translations.html#qt6-add-translations) like that in the CMakeLists.txt of the root project:

```
qt_add_translations(appTestLocalization TS_FILES i18n/lang_fr_FR.ts)
```

Then in Qt Creator I do `Ctrl+K` and I run `cm update_translations` (or `cm appTestLocalization_lupdate` but the result is the same)

However, the resulting ts files contain only the `qsTr` from the `Main.qml`.
So I've tried to add the module directory manually like that but the result is the same:

```
qt_add_translations(appTestLocalization 
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    MyModule
TS_FILES 
    i18n/lang_fr_FR.ts)
```

I also tried to add a translation in the module's `CMakeLists.txt` too:

```
qt_add_translations(mymodule TS_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/i18n/lang_fr_FR.ts)
```

But it overwrites the translations from the the root project...

How could I add module files to the Qt translation process?

**EDIT**:

I know I can add the files I want using the `SOURCE` argument like that:

```
qt_add_translations(appTestLocalization
    #SOURCES
        Main.qml
        MyModule/MyLabel.qml
    TS_FILES
        i18n/lang_fr_FR.ts
)
```

But it seems a "wrong" way as we could have a lot of files in several modules. This would be a nightmare to maintain and I would like to avoid that.

I have also tried passing `-recursive` to lupdate despite it should be the default, but it didn't work either:

```
qt_add_translations(appTestLocalization
    LUPDATE_OPTIONS -recursive
    TS_FILES
        i18n/lang_fr_FR.ts
)
```

Comment: You could try explicitly using the SOURCES field to add all of your source files.

Comment: @JarMan
Yeah it works, but I would rather avoid writing dozens of files in several modules. Besides it seems "wrong" to do that, it would be a nightmare to maintain and track down missing files. I will update my question to add that in it.

Comment: So why don't you use [`file(GLOB_RECURSE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse)?

Comment: I just did some research, and it seems that using multiple targets is added in future versions. https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qttools/+/495546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @smr you can scan the files to translate recursive. This is how we add translations to our application also build up of a bunch of modules:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE QML_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} *.qml)

qt_add_translations(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} TS_FILES
    ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_de_DE.ts
    ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}_en_EN.ts
    SOURCES ${QML_SOURCES}
    RESOURCE_PREFIX "/translations"
    LUPDATE_OPTIONS -no-obsolete
)
```

Comment: Does the `GLOB_RECURSE` will be properly updated? The [doc]() says `We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate`

Comment: Indeed you have to run CMake by hand after adding a new file if you are using any GLOB function.

Comment: @BenPyton Running lupdate doesn't need to happen very often, so it shouldn't cause many problems. You can manually run CMake after you have finished making changes.

Comment: yeah okay, I have no other choice at this moment but this solution. As @smr said in a comment, `qt_add_translations` will support multiple targets in Qt 6.7. Would be great to update this answer when it will be out.